# Express cookies not visible in Browser

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cookies, session-cookies

I am using Nodejs as Backend and Angular for front-end, I am trying to use cookies.

I am using the following code to set cookies:

```
const conf = {
                 signed: true,
                 path: "/",
                 secure: false,
                 maxAge: 60*60*10000000,
                 httpOnly: false,
              };
app.use(cookieParser());
res.cookie('name', 'val', conf);
```

When I use the same in local server, I can see Cookies being set in Chrome Dev-Tools Application.
When I deploy, the cookies are not visible in my angular application.
But the cookies are set, I don't know why they are not visible in browser also not accessible by javascript.

When I send a request from angular with `withCredentials:true`, with a debug statement in node server, `console.log(req.headers.cookie)` - I get the cookie.

But why the cookie is not showing in Browser.

Comment: hey I am having the exact issue... they are set in nodeJS with the next request, but I don't see them in the browser... did you figure it out? Are you using cors?

Comment: i think you are hosting frontend and backend on different platform and browser does not allow to set cross site cookie by default check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies